# installing local readthedocs with uwsgi

Tags: installation, django, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup a local instance of readthedocs for managing project documentation.  I believe I've got everything installed properly with readthedocs and it's dependencies in its own *virtualenv*, following: http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

`manage.py runserver` comes up without issue, so now I'm trying to set it up to be run with nginx+uwsgi.

Using Commandline from the '/var/www/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org' directory:

```
uwsgi --http :8111 --module readthedocs.wsgi --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=readthedocs.settings -H /var/www/rtd
```

I get the error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
>   Error importing module privacy.backends.syncers.DoubleRemotePuller: "No module named privacy.backends.syncers"

I suspect this is some kind of path issue, and the library can't be found, since it runs with `runserver`.

Does anyone have an clues to what I'm missing here?
Or, are there other recommended ways of running a local instance of readthedocs?

Referencing :
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when using `runserver`, "*readthedocs.settings.sqlite*" was being set as the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.  Updating the `uwsgi` line to match this resolved the `privacy.backends.syncers.DoubleRemotePuller` import issue

```
uwsgi --http :8111 --module readthedocs.wsgi --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=readthedocs.settings -H /var/www/rtd
```

However, this still seems as if it will be a problem when running with postgres.